# Adding an item to Gridster.js grid with native add_widget causing unknown errors

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, gridster

I've been trying all morning to add a simple item to a gridster grid but get errors in reference to gridsterjs' [add_widget](http://gridster.net/docs/classes/Gridster.html#method_add_widget) can someone please give me details on how to dynamically add widgets?

Perhaps I'm not instantiating correctly or missing a dependency...

```
$(function(){
    gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
        widget_margins: [10, 10],
        widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140]
    });

    // errors why?
    gridster.add_widget.apply(gridster, ['<li class="gw_s">The HTML of the widget...</li>', 2, 1]); // Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    gridster.add_widget('<li class="gw_s">The HTML of the widget...</li>', 2, 1); // Uncaught TypeError: gridster.add_widget is not a function

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how you get the gridster object.. Try this:

```
$(".gridster ul").gridster({
    widget_margins: [10, 10],
    widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140]
});
var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');
```

Now you can use the function `gridster.add_widget(html, 2, 1);`

Comment: Wow, I have never seen that code to get the gridster object. Is there anything I should know moving forward or references to go to? Thanks @pierreDuc!